Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'module') in Angular unit tests after upgrading to 17
Originally, the unit tests are working fine at Angular 15.
We recently upgrade the project to Angular 17, and now all unit test files (those end with .spec.ts) are throwing errors like this:
./src/app/shared/utility/utility.service.spec.ts - Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'module')

The test file itself can be as simple as this:
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { UtilityService } from './utility.service';

describe('UtilityService', () => {
  let service: UtilityService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(UtilityService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

I have asked AI and it provided me several suggestions, but the error still persists. The suggestions I have tried include:

Adding the following to the tsconfig.spec.json inside the compilerOptions section:
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"allowJs": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"resolveJsonModule": true


Ensure the polyfills.ts and test.ts are included in angular.json


Check if all dependencies are installed correctly.


Check if any test file has "require" instead of "import".


Check if the relevant services/components are imported correctly in the test files.


Create a plain Angular 17 project and compare the difference. (For this one, I tried the configuration in Angular 17 and it works there. Perhaps this is caused by some dependencies.)

Now it seems the AI is out of ideas and start repeating itself. So, I am posting a question here to see if anyone has encountered the similar issue before. Thanks in advance for any suggestions or solutions!
In case it is relevant, this is a Spartacus SAP project and we are using the latest 2211 version.

Perhaps is as you said and is caused by some dependency, did you try to clean up the node_modules, cache, as well the package-lock.json?

@OscarLudick Just tried, the error messages are still the same.

Is that the complete error message? If not, can you share the complete error message? Could you also include the UtilityService in your question because the test looks fine, so the problem might be elsewhere.

@Verity The problem is, this is the complete error message, but this error message is being thrown by all unit tests, not just the one I am showing here. I think there might be something more general behind it.
